# Python - multiprocessing and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

**Question:**

I am trying to gain a better understanding of Python's multiprocessing and multithreading, particularly in the context of using the `concurrent.futures` module. I want to make sure my understanding is correct.

**Multiprocessing:**

I believe that multiprocessing creates multiple processes, each with its own Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and memory space. These processes can efficiently utilize multiple CPU cores. **And, each independent process automatically manages its own threads.**

Here is an example of using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```py
# Create a ProcessPoolExecutor with a maximum of 4 concurrent processes
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
    # Use the executor to map your function to the list of numbers
    results = list(executor.map(calculate_square, numbers))
```

**Multithreading:**

In contrast, multithreading creates multiple threads within a single process. These threads share the same memory space and GIL. Multithreading is typically more suitable for I/O-bound tasks rather than CPU-bound tasks. However, it doesn't utilize multiple CPU cores, so even if you have 4 cores a program only uses one core where it runs x number of threads.

Here is an example of using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```py
# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with a specified maximum number of threads
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_threads) as executor:
    # Use the executor to map your function to the list of numbers
    results = list(executor.map(calculate_square, numbers))
```

**hybrid**

It’s possible to combine the concurrent.futures thread and process pool to handle both I/O and CPU intensive tasks by creating multiple processes with its own threads.

Comment: Sounds correct to me.

Comment: More or less accurate, except that multithreading in Python *can* work for CPU-bound tasks as well — provided they are mostly happening in native libraries. If you tell Numpy to do some big heavy computation, it will actually release the lock allowing you to run multiple Numpy tasks in parallel via threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IO-sensitive programs, using multithreading alone is sufficient, and it could utilize multiple cores. [The GIL will be released around potentially blocking I/O operations like reading or writing a file](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code).

If the workload involves a hybrid of CPU and IO tasks, you might consider to use the combination of multiple process and threading.

```
def run_child():
    "run in child process"
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    # create a thread pool to run tasks
    # ...

def main():
    pool = Pool()  # multiprocessing
    pool.apply_async(run_child)
```

Furthermore, for IO-sensitive tasks, coroutine might be a better option, also you could consider the combination multiple process and coroutine.

Comment: But when creating a process pool executor that spawns multiple processes, does each process automatically manage its threads? That what I don’t understand.

Comment: Not quite sure  what does "automatically manage its thread" referring to. Each process will have its dedicated threads.

Comment: Let me reformulate, when using the process pool executor to spawn let’s say 10 parallel processes - does Python decide number of threads inside each individual process or what?

Comment: Python doesn't decide that.  Each process starts out with one main thread.  If you create more, then there will be more.  If you don't, then there's just one.

Comment: @uba2012 As Tim said, each child process will start with one single (main) thread. With fork start method, when fork(2) is called in a multithreaded process, only the calling thread is duplicated in the child process.  With spawn start method, the parent process starts a fresh Python interpreter process. See more information in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods